# Adding an attachment on Azure CosmosDB

Tags: java, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I am looking for some help on how to add an attachment on CosmosDB. Here is the little background.

Our application is currently on IBM Bluemix and we are using CloudantDB. We use CloudanDB to store attachments (PDF file). We are no moving to Azure PaaS App Service and planning to use CosmosDB. I am looking for help on how to create an attachment on CosmosDB using Java API. What API do I need to use? I want to do a small POC.

Thanks,

Comment: Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think that is the only way. I am looking at some other options out consmosDB.. Like CouchDB. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You're welcome.If you adopt answer , you could mark it for others' reference on the forum.Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Well Personally i feel In Azure, if you go want to put files into documentDb, you will pay high for the query cost. Instead it would be normal practice to use Azure blob and save the link in a field, and then return url if its public or binary data if you want it to be secured.

However, You could store it using

```
var myDoc = new { id = "42", Name = "Max", City="Aberdeen" }; // this is the document you are trying to save
var attachmentStream = File.OpenRead("c:/Path/To/File.pdf"); // this is the document stream you are attaching

var client = await GetClientAsync();
var createUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName);
Document document = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(createUrl, myDoc);

await client.CreateAttachmentAsync(document.SelfLink, attachmentStream, new MediaOptions()
    {
        ContentType = "application/pdf", // your application type
        Slug = "78", // this is actually attachment ID
    });
```

**[WORKING WITH ATTACHMENTS](https://tech.trailmax.info/2017/05/working-with-attachments-in-documentdb/)**

I have answered a similar question **[`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343675/how-can-i-store-images-in-azure-cosmos-db)**

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to both. In the documentation it says, total file size we can store is 2GB. "Azure Cosmos DB allows you to store binary blobs/media either with Azure Cosmos DB (maximum of 2 GB per account) " Is it the max we can store?

Comment: Another question I have, we are using Java. What client API I can use?

Comment: You should use the SDK, here is a sample code https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/cfe3c85766a6ce142c54c4e72db5bc4e907be24d/sdk/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/rx/AttachmentCrudTest.java

Answer (score 1):

> What client API I can use?

You could follow the [cosmos db java sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/cfe3c85766a6ce142c54c4e72db5bc4e907be24d/sdk/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/rx/AttachmentCrudTest.java#L64) to CRUD attachment.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CreateAttachment {

    // Replace with your DocumentDB end point and master key.
    private static final String END_POINT = "***";
    private static final String MASTER_KEY = "***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(END_POINT,
                MASTER_KEY, ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Attachment attachment = getAttachmentDefinition(uuid, "application/text");

        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();

        ResourceResponse<Attachment> attachmentResourceResponse = documentClient.createAttachment(getDocumentLink(), attachment, options);

    }

    private static Attachment getAttachmentDefinition(String uuid, String type) {
        return new Attachment(String.format(
                "{" +
                        "  'id': '%s'," +
                        "  'media': 'http://xstore.'," +
                        "  'MediaType': 'Book'," +
                        "  'Author': 'My Book Author'," +
                        "  'Title': 'My Book Title'," +
                        "  'contentType': '%s'" +
                        "}", uuid, type));
    }
}
```

> In the documentation it says, total file size we can store is 2GB.
>   "Azure Cosmos DB allows you to store binary blobs/media either with
>   Azure Cosmos DB (maximum of 2 GB per account) " Is it the max we can
>   store?

Yes.The size of attachments is limited in document db. However, there are two methods for creating a Azure Cosmos DB Document Attachment.

**1.Store the file as an attachment to a Document**

The raw attachment is included as the body of the POST.
Two headers must be set:

Slug – The name of the attachment.
contentType – Set to the MIME type of the attachment.

**2.Store the URL for the file in an attachment to a Document**

The body for the POST include the following.

id – It is the unique name that identifies the attachment, i.e. no two attachments will share the same id. The id must not exceed 255 characters.
Media – This is the URL link or file path where the attachment resides.

The following is an example

```
{  
    "id": "device\A234",  
    "contentType": "application/x-zip-compressed",  
    "media": "www.bing.com/A234.zip"  
}
```

If your files are over limitation , you could try to store them with second way. More details, please refer to [blog](https://docdb.info/azure-cosmos-db-document-attachment-storage-comparison/).

In addition, you could notice that cosmos db attachments support 
garbage collect mechanism,it ensures to garbage collect the media when all of the outstanding references are dropped.

Hope it helps you.