# Xamarin forms : Cannot Upload Image in cosmos db as a string [COSOMS DB SDK3 | IMAGE CROPPER | ToBase64String]

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarin forms,

I am trying to upload profile images in my Xamarin cosmos db but it is not working and I have this warning message :

```
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : RNTBD call timed out on channel xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx -> xx.xx.xx.x:xxxxx. Error: SendTimeout
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code RequestTimeout, message: Message: Request timed out. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-request-timeout, inner exception: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportException: A client transport error occurred: Sending the request timed out. (Time: 2023-01-14T19:10:07.2121350Z, activity ID: 38c1b0d0-847e-4eff-bb41-dfc541489b24, error code: SendTimeout [0x000E], base error: HRESULT 0x80131500, URI: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-xxxxpartitions/xxxxx/replicas/xxxxx/, connection: xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx -> xx.xx.xx.x:xxxxx, payload sent: True)
  at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.Channel.RequestAsync (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest request, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceOperation resourceOperation, System.Guid activityId, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportRequestStats transportRequestStats) [0x0035a] in <ffe3c00d433342948947b1c93a852e2f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.LoadBalancingPartition.RequestAsync (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest request, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceOperation resourceOperation, System.Guid activityId, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportRequestStats transportRequestStats) [0x001ad] in <ffe3c00d433342948947b1c93a852e2f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.TransportClient.InvokeStoreAsync (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ResourceOperation resourceOperation, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentServiceRequest request) [0x0015c] in <ffe3c00d433342948947b1c93a852e2f>:0 , and response headers: null
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : ClientRetryPolicy: RequestTimeout. Failed Location: https://xxxxxx.documents.azure.com/; ResourceAddress: dbs/xxxxx/colls/xxxx/docs/6957c0bb-e3cb-4cc3-8b04-3bbef4b85c37
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : Operation will NOT be retried. Current attempt 0, Status Code: RequestTimeout
```

My methode :
I am using [image cropper](https://github.com/INHack20/ImageCropper.Forms) library to crop my image. Then read my image as stream then convert to ToBase64String then upload image in cosmos db as string

Here is how I read and upload the image :

```
var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions {});


if (result != null)
{
    //using ImaCropper La
    new ImageCropper()
    {
        CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Oval,
        AspectRatioX = 1,
        AspectRatioY = 1,

        Success = (imageFile) =>
        {


            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                Stream stream = File.OpenRead(imageFile);


                byte[] bytes;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    // this is a string 
                    UserConnected.UserImage = MySharedAppClasses.BitmapToBase64(bytes);


                  
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        // I can see the image succefully displayed in my APP
                        ProfileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(MySharedAppClasses.Base64ToBitmap(UserConnected.UserImage)));

                    });
                    
                    Here I upload my Image
                    MySharedAppClasses.UpdateUserInfos(UserConnected);
                }



            });


        }
    }.Show(this, result.FullPath);


}
```

Here is the upload function for cosmos DB :

```
public async static Task<MyUser> UpdateUserAsync(MyUser myUser)
{
try          
{
    

    ItemResponse<MyUser> response = await container.ReplaceItemAsync(myUser, myUser.MyId.ToString());
    return response.Resource;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ErrorManager.InsertErrorAsync("update user error", e.Message);
    return null;
}


}
```

Here is my Model class :

```
public class MyUser
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid MyId { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userimage")]
    public string UserImage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-request-timeout?tabs=cpu-new

Comment: It’s timing out.  I’d guess your request is too large with the image data.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343675/how-can-i-store-images-in-azure-cosmos-db

Comment: @Jason this cannot be used for comos db SDK3